# Where are the best places to farm Mytes and Greebles?

Tags: high-on-life

For the Bounty Hunter forums achievement ("Mods Please Ban"), we're tasked with killing a lot of these enemies but I can only find a handful at a time. Where's a good place to farm these and is there any easy way to track progress?